# Printing flight statuses

Tags: ruby

I have a serious nesting of `if`s in a helper code and I would like to making cleaner. I would like to avoid `case` if possible as well.

I know there is probably a more object-oriented approach to this but I can't seem to know how.

I'm flooded with stuff like this:

```
  def print_flight_options_status(invitation)
    if invitation.group.travel_class == 'none'
      not_allowed
    elsif invitation.refused_flight_options?
      not_needed
    elsif invitation.selected_flights?
      waiting_reservation
    elsif invitation.flight_options.empty?
      not_sent_yet
    elsif invitation.requested_more_flight_options?
      rejected
    else
      waiting_guest_input
    end
  end

  def print_event_terms_status(invitation)
    if invitation.event_terms_status.nil?
      "<span class='grey_highlight pj_cat'>Aguardando</span>"
    elsif invitation.accepted_event_terms?
      "<span class='green_highlight pj_cat'>Aceito</span>"
    elsif invitation.rejected_event_terms?
      "<span class='red_highlight pj_cat'>Declinado</span>"
    elsif invitation.cancelled_event_terms?
      "<span class='yellow_highlight pj_cat'>Cancelado</span>"
    end.html_safe
  end
```

Comment: If the return values are mutually exclusive, it seems like it would make more sense to have print_flight_options_status contain a symbol that is updated by the various things you are querying.

Comment: You're right, this would probably be cleaner, but the complexity would not be much reduced.

Comment: `print_flight_options_status` looks fantastic as it is, I wouldn't write it as in-line `if`s. At most,  to reduce the line-count, I'd use `if condition then value ... `, but it won't look as nice. In `print_event_terms_status` I'd just use helpers for the HTML tags instead of building them by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer this style:

```
  def print_flight_options_status(invitation)
    return not_allowed         if invitation.group.travel_class == 'none'
    return not_needed          if invitation.refused_flight_options?
    return waiting_reservation if invitation.selected_flights?
    return not_sent_yet        if invitation.flight_options.empty?
    return rejected            if invitation.requested_more_flight_options?

    waiting_guest_input
  end
```

UPD

About second code-snippet. I think in this case you can use decorators (for example [draper](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper)) for invitations, so:

```
def print_event_terms_status(invitation)
  InvitationDecorator.decorate(invitation).status_in_html
end
```

Where `InvitationDecorator`:

```
class InvitationDecorator < Draper::Base
  def status_in_html
    if invitation.event_terms_status.nil?
      "<span class='grey_highlight pj_cat'>Aguardando</span>"
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: The problem with inline return + conditionals is that the exit points of the method grow up... I know it's a common pattern in Ruby but personally I consider it dubious.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `case`-variant which may be a bit better:

```
x = ''
case 
  when x == 'xxy'
    puts '=xxy'
  when x.empty?
    puts 'is empty'
  else
    puts "well, I don't know, what it is"
  end
```

In your case, you could use:

```
def print_flight_options_status(invitation)
  case
    when invitation.group.travel_class == 'none'
      not_allowed
    when invitation.refused_flight_options?
      not_needed
    when invitation.selected_flights?
      waiting_reservation
    when invitation.flight_options.empty?
      not_sent_yet
    when invitation.requested_more_flight_options?
      rejected
    else
      waiting_guest_input
    end
  end
```

---

You may also define a kind of `with`-statement:

```
module With
  def with(&block)
    self.instance_eval &block
  end
end

['a', ''].each{|test|
  test.extend(With)
  p test.with{
    if empty? 
      :empty
    elsif self == 'a'
      :a
    else
      :else
    end
  }  
}
```

In your case:

```
def print_flight_options_status(invitation)
  invitation.extend(With)
  invitation.with{
    if group.travel_class == 'none'
        not_allowed
      elsif refused_flight_options?
        not_needed
      elsif selected_flights?
        waiting_reservation
      elsif flight_options.empty?
        not_sent_yet
      elsif requested_more_flight_options?
        rejected
      else
        waiting_guest_input
      end
    }
  end
```

Advantage: You don't need to repeat `invitation.`.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO both variants look ok regarding ifs. They clearly express business logic and well formatted. Maybe I'd separate a bit markup from UI Logic:

```
def print_event_terms_status(invitation)
  span = 
    ->(cls, text) { "<span class='#{class} pj_cat'>#{text}</span>".html_safe }
  if invitation.event_terms_status.nil?
    span['grey_highlight', 'Aguardando']
  elsif invitation.accepted_event_terms?
    span['green_highlight', 'Aceito']
  elsif invitation.rejected_event_terms?
    span['red_highlight', 'Declinado']
  elsif invitation.cancelled_event_terms?
    span['yellow_highlight', 'Cancelado']
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of CSS is to decouple the presentation from the logic.  Therefore, you should not hard-code colours into the CSS class names.  Each colour should be mentioned just once, in the style rule only:

```
.pj_cat.pending {
    background-color: gray;
}
.pj_cat.accepted {
    background-color: green;
}
.pj_cat.rejected {
    background-color: red;
}
.pj_cat.cancelled {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Otherwise, if the site's colour theme ever changes, the code is going to be confusing.